# ReactNative 0.43-rc.2 FlatList -- Tried to get frame for out of range index 0

Tags: react-native

I have a question specific to 0.43-rc.2
I migrated a ListView to a FlatList, and I now get the following error:

```
TaskQueue: Error with task: Tried to get frame for out of range index 0
```

which originates form the `VirtualizedList` class.

If I ignore the error, the list seems to work fine, so I'm really at a loss as to what is wrong.

I can't seem to find any information on why this would happen. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like this only happens when the array passed to FlatList is empty. I was able to get around this by replacing the list with a `View` in the case that the data was empty.

Comment: Passing null instead of empty array seemed to fix that bug for me. Any other hints?

Comment: this statement clicked my mind and I have resolved the error. Thanks @Mobius

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I had debug={true}. Removing that fixed it for me.

Comment: It is not fix. If you not fix properly you will get performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a JSON response to render in my FlatList and there I was passing a wrong data response, that was the reason this error was coming.

Answer (score 0):

**Just make sure you are always passing an array to flatlist**

This error will come when you are not passing an array in data property of flatlist. Just pass an empty array to flatlist when there's no data rather than empty object or null.

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen if you pass in numColumns < 1.

Answer (score 0):

For me it will happen when I pass an object to data props instead of array

Answer (score 0):

The array should be passed instead of the object when initializing it

Eg: `let dataArray = [{data:1},{date:2},{data:3}]`  - Good format for flatlist

```js
let dataArray =
{
    [{data:1},
    {date:2},
    {data:3}]
}  // bad format for flat list
```

The summary array should show have square bracket `[]` during initialization